# fat-free framework variable not accessible

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

I tried setting a variable from one class's function, and access it in other class.

```
ExportController.php->export():

$this->f3->set('employee', $employee);
$this->f3->set('leave', $leave);
$this->reroute('/leave/export/' . $date . '/' . $date1);
```

The route points to following function of the controller file:

```
LeaveController.php->exportLeave():

echo $this->f3->get('leave');
echo '<br/>'.$this->f3->get('employee');
```

But I am getting nothing. I have been using this most of the time and setting and getting variables have not been any problem.

Could it be because of `$this->reroute()`?

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: reroute is a header redirect 302, the *hive* won't hold the state of your previous set variables.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone thank you . :)

Comment: You got `$this->f3->set('SESSION.employee', $employee)` though, just got to set it up. see: https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/session

Comment: @LawrenceCherone yes I am storing it in session variables. thanks

Comment: no worries, its nice to see a fat-free question.